# Why $|G|$ even implies $|A(G)|$ also even?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be finite group with even order. Why has the set $A(G)=\{g\in G: g\neq g^{-1}\}$ an even number of elements?

Comment: It seems to me that $A(G)$ has an even number of elements irrespective of whether $|G|$ is odd or even. If $g\in A(G)$, then also $g^{-1}\in A(G)$ as $(g^{-1})^{-1}=g$.

Comment: I might be missing something- but $g \in A(G)$ implies that $g^{-1}$ is in $A(G)$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you're right, I guess the hypothesis of $|G|$ even is not necessary..

Answer (score 5):

For any finite group doesn't your set $A(G)$ have even order, since we can pair each element of $A(G)$ with it's inverse.

On the other hand if $G$ has even order, then I guess $G-A(G)=\{g\in G : g=g^{-1}\}$ has even order.

Comment: As to your second statement if $G-A(G)$ has even order then $G=(G-A(G))\cup A(G)$ (disjoint union) implies $|G|=|G-A(G)|+|A(G)|$ hence $|A(G)|$ should also have even order, right?

Comment: @PtF Yeah, but that’d be a circular argument. It *directly* follows for *any* finite group $G$ that $A(G)$ has an even number of elements. The second statement is just a corollary and doesn’t have to be used (nor should it be) to again show that $|A(G)|$ is even.

Comment: Right, I had misunderstood your comment, sorry..